# Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure corresponding to a right continuous increasing function, $m(\{x\}) = \alpha(x) - \alpha(x-)$ for each $x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $m$ be Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure corresponding to a right continuous increasing function $\alpha$. How do I see that for each $x$, we have$$m(\{x\}) = \alpha(x) - \alpha(x-)?$$

Answer (score 4):

Take a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n \to x$ and $x_j < x $ for each $j$. Then write $\{x\}=\bigcap_{n} (x_n,x]$. By continuity from above, $m(\{x\})=\lim_{n\to \infty} m((x_n,x])=\lim_{n\to \infty} \alpha(x)-\alpha(x_n)=\alpha(x)-\alpha(x-)$